# Unable to locate javax.ImageIO

Tags: java, eclipse, javax.imageio

I am trying to do some practice in Java and for some reason I don't have javax. I get this error in Eclipse:

[image: Error]

And when manually adding the import:

[image: Error 2]
There is no option to import ImageIO, and when I looked online I found no way to download javax nor any tutorials on how to get it. Hope someone can help with this!

Comment: The import should look like: `import javax.imageio.ImageIO;`. As a side note, that empty catch block has me a bit worried.

Comment: Yes I tried manually putting that in but it can't recognize the import either, also I just fixed the catch block, thanks for pointing that out haha

Comment: [This gets asked a lot](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1LEND_enUS445US445&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java%20eclipse%20cannot%20be%20resolved)